# Magento2 Stable Release - Render Layout not working in custom module

Tags: layout, blocks, magento2, module, controllers

My module was working perfectly in Magento2 Beta version. In stable version, module is getting listed and custom module backend is working fine. However frontend pages of my module are not working. Here is my code.

**Index Controller**

```
namespace Companyname\Modulename\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends Action {
    public function execute() { 
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();   
    }

}
```

**Layout - /app/code/Companyname/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/modulename_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Companyname\Modulename\Block\Modulename" name="modulename" template="Companyname_Modulename::modulename.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>        
    </body>
</page>
```

**Block File**

```
namespace Companyname\Modulename\Block;
class Modulename extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {
   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, 
        array $data = array()
    ) {     
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }    
}
```

When i debug, it does not come in construct of the block. I am assuming that it is not able to find the block. The phtml file simply prints `echo "hello world";` But nothing appears on frontend. Any ideas as to what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think issue in your `modulename_index_index.xml` file, You have to mention page layout like `layout="1column"`.

You can change your page layout

- 1column
- 2columns-left
- 2columns-right
- 3columns

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the layout for the page.
So add this `layout="2columns-left"` on the `<page>` node in `hello_index_index.xml`.
You can also use `1column`, `2columns-right`, `3columns` or `empty`.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your controller is executed, if not check routes.

Additionally, layout is not supposed to be manipulated directly via `view` object in controller (like it was in Magento 1), result page object should be created instead.

Please consider rewriting your controller as follow:

```
<?php
namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Some action.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your request coming to Index controller ?

Comment: Can you please load your block name using $this->_view->getLayout()
        ->getBlock('modulename'); after         $this->_view->loadLayout();

Comment: have you tried using clear cache ? @ReenaParekh

Comment: @ReenaParekh Regarding blank page, unfortunately you are right, it is still not possible to avoid inheritance from action controller, but you still should use result page object. Updated example.

Comment: Try to clear `var/generation`, most likely you have old proxy there. Also, have you cleared `pub/static` and the whole `var/*` ?

Comment: the problem was in layout file. Thanks though for sharing your insights :)